# Unobscate JS code that is in HEX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, encryption

guys!
I started working on a project from a website that another company created, however I need to unhide JS gives page for me to make the necessary changes. The original code is this one:

```
var _0xafdc=["\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79","\x65\x78\x74\x65\x6E\x64\x73","","\x2D\x6D\x6F\x7A\x2D","\x2D\x6D\x73\x2D","\x2D\x6F\x2D","\x2D\x77\x65\x62\x6B\x69\x74\x2D","\x2D\x6B\x68\x74\x6D\x6C\x2D","\x6E\x6F\x64\x65\x4E\x61\x6D\x65","\x23\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68","\x6F\x62\x6A\x65\x63\x74","\x69\x67","\x65\x78\x74\x72\x61","\x74\x68\x69\x73","\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6F\x72\x41\x6C\x6C","\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79\x53\x74\x61\x74\x65","\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x69\x6E\x67","\x44\x4F\x4D\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x4C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x64","\x61\x64\x64\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x4C\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6E\x65\x72","\x6B\x65\x79\x73","\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65","\x75\x73\x65\x20\x73\x74\x72\x69\x63\x74","\x68\x61\x73\x4F\x77\x6E\x50\x72\x6F\x70\x65\x72\x74\x79","\x3D","\x70\x75\x73\x68","\x26","\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E","\x63\x61\x6C\x6C","\x74\x6F\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","\x70\x72\x6F\x74\x6F\x74\x79\x70\x65","\x5B\x6F\x62\x6A\x65\x63\x74\x20\x4F\x62\x6A\x65\x63\x74\x5D","\x64\x65\x65\x70\x53\x74\x72","\x6B\x65\x79\x70\x72\x65\x73\x73","\x6B\x65\x79\x64\x6F\x77\x6E","\x6B\x65\x79\x75\x70","\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x6D\x6F\x75\x73\x65\x64\x6F\x77\x6E","\x6D\x6F\x75\x73\x65\x75\x70","\x6D\x6F\x75\x73\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65","\x63\x68\x61\x6E\x67\x65","\x74\x69\x6D\x65\x75\x70\x64\x61\x74\x65","\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74","\x61\x74\x74\x72\x73\x65\x74","\x61\x74\x74\x72\x67\x65\x74","\x58\x4D\x4C\x48\x74\x74\x70\x52\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74","\x4D\x69\x63\x72\x6F\x73\x6F\x66\x74\x2E\x58\x4D\x4C\x48\x54\x54\x50","\x75\x72\x6C","\x74\x6F\x55\x70\x70\x65\x72\x43\x61\x73\x65","\x74\x79\x70\x65","\x64\x61\x74\x61\x54\x79\x70\x65","\x64\x61\x74\x61","\x50\x4F\x53\x54","\x6F\x70\x65\x6E","\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x2D\x74\x79\x70\x65","\x61\x70\x70\x6C\x69\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2F\x78\x2D\x77\x77\x77\x2D\x66\x6F\x72\x6D\x2D\x75\x72\x6C\x65\x6E\x63\x6F\x64\x65\x64","\x73\x65\x74\x52\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x48\x65\x61\x64\x65\x72","\x43\x61\x63\x68\x65\x2D\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x72\x6F\x6C","\x6E\x6F\x2D\x63\x61\x63\x68\x65","\x50\x72\x61\x67\x6D\x61","\x49\x66\x2D\x4D\x6F\x64\x69\x66\x69\x65\x64\x2D\x53\x69\x6E\x63\x65","\x53\x61\x74\x2C\x20\x31\x20\x4A\x61\x6E\x20\x32\x30\x30\x30\x20\x30\x30\x3A\x30\x30\x3A\x30\x30\x20\x47\x4D\x54","\x73\x65\x6E\x64","\x47\x45\x54","\x3F","\x6F\x6E\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79\x73\x74\x61\x74\x65\x63\x68\x61\x6E\x67\x65","\x73\x74\x61\x74\x75\x73","\x4A\x53\x4F\x4E","\x72\x65\x73\x70\x6F\x6E\x73\x65\x54\x65\x78\x74","\x70\x61\x72\x73\x65","\x73\x75\x63\x63\x65\x73\x73","\x66\x61\xE7\x61\x20\x75\x6D\x20\x63\x61\x6C\x6C\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x20\x73\x75\x63\x63\x65\x73\x73","\x6C\x6F\x67","\x66\x61\x69\x6C","\x66\x61\xE7\x61\x20\x75\x6D\x20\x63\x61\x6C\x6C\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x20\x66\x61\x69\x6C","\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C","\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65","\x6D\x61\x74\x63\x68","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x2C","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65","\x73\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65\x4E\x6F\x64\x65","\x64\x69\x73\x70\x6C\x61\x79","\x62\x6C\x6F\x63\x6B","\x6F\x70\x61\x63\x69\x74\x79","\x72\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x41\x6E\x69\x6D\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x46\x72\x61\x6D\x65","\x6E\x6F\x6E\x65","\x74\x72\x61\x6E\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2D\x64\x75\x72\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x31\x73","\x73","\x63\x73\x73","\x67\x65\x74\x72\x65\x74","\x72\x6F\x77","\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x70\x61\x72\x65\x6E\x74\x4E\x6F\x64\x65","\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x72\x65\x6E","\x74\x65\x73\x74\x65","\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74","\x74\x61\x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65","\x6C\x69","\x67\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65","\x73\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65"];function tSec(_0x17e3x2){if( typeof (_0x17e3x2)=== _0xafdc[0]){return t[_0xafdc[2]][_0xafdc[1]](_0x17e3x2)}else {return t(_0x17e3x2)}}var t;t= _0xafdc[3];var prefixes=[_0xafdc[4],_0xafdc[5],_0xafdc[6],_0xafdc[7],_0xafdc[8]];t= function(_0x17e3x5){newdocument= doc();type= newdocument;sl= _0xafdc[3];get= _0xafdc[3];type= _0x17e3x5[_0xafdc[9]];sl= _0x17e3x5;if(type== _0xafdc[10]){get= _0x17e3x5;return t[_0xafdc[2]]}else {if(_0x17e3x5== undefined|| _0x17e3x5[_0xafdc[11]]== 0){}else {if( typeof (_0x17e3x5)=== _0xafdc[12]){get= _0x17e3x5;return t[_0xafdc[2]]}else {if( typeof (_0x17e3x5)=== _0xafdc[13]){return t[_0xafdc[2]]}else {if( typeof (_0x17e3x5)=== _0xafdc[14]){return t[_0xafdc[2]]}else {if( typeof (_0x17e3x5)=== _0xafdc[15]){return t[_0xafdc[2]]}else {if( typeof (_0x17e3x5)=== _0xafdc[16]){get= newdocument[_0xafdc[17]](_0x17e3x5);return t[_0xafdc[2]]}else {get= _0x17e3x5;return t[_0xafdc[2]]}}}}}}}};t[_0xafdc[2]]= {ready:function(_0x17e3x2){if(doc()[_0xafdc[18]]!= _0xafdc[19]){_0x17e3x2()}else {doc()[_0xafdc[21]](_0xafdc[20],_0x17e3x2)}},css:function(_0x17e3x6,_0x17e3x7){var _0x17e3x8=get;var _0x17e3x9=Object[_0xafdc[22]](_0x17e3x8)[_0xafdc[11]];var _0x17e3xa=Object[_0xafdc[22]](_0x17e3x8)[_0xafdc[11]];if(_0x17e3x9> 0){if(_0x17e3x6[_0xafdc[11]]> 0&& _0x17e3x7[_0xafdc[11]]> 0){_0x17e3x8[0][_0xafdc[23]][_0x17e3x6]= _0x17e3x7}else {if(_0x17e3x9<= 1){for(var _0x17e3xb in _0x17e3x6){if(_0x17e3xa<= 0){_0x17e3x8[_0xafdc[23]][_0x17e3xb]= _0x17e3x6[_0x17e3xb]}else {_0x17e3x8[0][_0xafdc[23]][_0x17e3xb]= _0x17e3x6[_0x17e3xb]}}}else {for(var _0x17e3xb in get){var _0x17e3xc=_0x17e3x8[_0x17e3xb];for(var _0x17e3xb in _0x17e3x6){var _0x17e3xd=_0x17e3x6[_0x17e3xb];if( typeof (_0x17e3xc)!= _0xafdc[12]){}else {_0x17e3xc[_0xafdc[23]][_0x17e3xb]= _0x17e3xd}}}}}}},str:function(_0x17e3xe){_0xafdc[24];var _0x17e3xf=[];for(var _0x17e3x10 in _0x17e3xe){if(!_0x17e3xe[_0xafdc[25]](_0x17e3x10)){continue};_0x17e3xf[_0xafdc[27]](_0x17e3x10+ _0xafdc[26]+ _0x17e3xe[_0x17e3x10])};return _0x17e3xf[_0xafdc[29]](_0xafdc[28])},deepStr:function(_0x17e3xe){var _0x17e3xf=[];for(var _0x17e3x10 in _0x17e3xe){if(!_0x17e3xe[_0xafdc[25]](_0x17e3x10)){continue};if(Object[_0xafdc[32]][_0xafdc[31]][_0xafdc[30]](_0x17e3xe[_0x17e3x10])=== _0xafdc[33]){_0x17e3xf[_0xafdc[27]](t[_0xafdc[34]](_0x17e3xe[_0x17e3x10]));continue};_0x17e3xf[_0xafdc[27]](_0x17e3x10+ _0xafdc[26]+ _0x17e3xe[_0x17e3x10])};return _0x17e3xf[_0xafdc[29]](_0xafdc[28])},keypress:function(_0x17e3x11){var _0x17e3x12=sl;var _0x17e3x8=document[_0xafdc[17]](sl);for(var _0x17e3xb=0;_0x17e3xb< get[_0xafdc[11]];_0x17e3xb++){_0x17e3x8[_0x17e3xb][_0xafdc[21]](_0xafdc[35],_0x17e3x11,true)}},keydown:function(_0x17e3x11){var _0x17e3x12=sl;var _0x17e3x8=document[_0xafdc[17]](sl);for(var _0x17e3xb=0;_0x17e3xb< get[_0xafdc[11]];_0x17e3xb++){_0x17e3x8[_0x17e3xb][_0xafdc[21]](_0xafdc[36],_0x17e3x11,true)}},keyup:function(_0x17e3x11){var _0x17e3x12=sl;var _0x17e3x8=document[_0xafdc[17]](sl);for(var _0x17e3xb=0;_0x17e3xb< get[_0xafdc[11]];_0x17e3xb++){_0x17e3x8[_0x17e3xb][_0xafdc[21]](_0xafdc[37],_0x17e3x11,true)}},click:function(_0x17e3x11){var _0x17e3x12=sl;var _0x17e3x8=document[_0xafdc[17]](sl);for(var _0x17e3xb=0;_0x17e3xb< get[_0xafdc[11]];_0x17e3xb++){_0x17e3x8[_0x17e3xb][_0xafdc[21]](_0xafdc[38],_0x17e3x11,true)}},mousedown:function(_0x17e3x11){var _0x17e3x12=sl;var _0x17e3x8=document[_0xafdc[17]](sl);for(var _0x17e3xb=0;_0x17e3xb< get[_0xafdc[11]];_0x17e3xb++){_0x17e3x8[_0x17e3xb][_0xafdc[21]](_0xafdc[39],_0x17e3x11,true)}},mouseup:function(_0x17e3x11){var _0x17e3x12=sl;var _0x17e3x8=document[_0xafdc[17]](sl);for(var _0x17e3xb=0;_0x17e3xb< get[_0xafdc[11]];_0x17e3xb++){_0x17e3x8[_0x17e3xb][_0xafdc[21]](_0xafdc[40],_0x17e3x11,true)}},mousemove:function(_0x17e3x11){var _0x17e3x12=sl;var _0x17e3x8=document[_0xafdc[17]](sl);for(var _0x17e3xb=0;_0x17e3xb< get[_0xafdc[11]];_0x17e3xb++){_0x17e3x8[_0x17e3xb][_0xafdc[21]](_0xafdc[41],_0x17e3x11,true)}},change:function(_0x17e3x11){var _0x17e3x12=sl;var _0x17e3x8=document[_0xafdc[17]](sl);for(var _0x17e3xb=0;_0x17e3xb< get[_0xafdc[11]];_0x17e3xb++){_0x17e3x8[_0x17e3xb][_0xafdc[21]](_0xafdc[42],_0x17e3x11,true)}},timeupdate:function(_0x17e3x11){var _0x17e3x12=sl;var _0x17e3x8=document[_0xafdc[17]](sl);for(var _0x17e3xb=0;_0x17e3xb< get[_0xafdc[11]];_0x17e3xb++){_0x17e3x8[_0x17e3xb][_0xafdc[21]](_0xafdc[43],_0x17e3x11,true)}},submit:function(_0x17e3x11){var _0x17e3x12=sl;var _0x17e3x8=document[_0xafdc[17]](sl);for(var _0x17e3xb=0;_0x17e3xb< get[_0xafdc[11]];_0x17e3xb++){_0x17e3x8[_0x17e3xb][_0xafdc[21]](_0xafdc[44],_0x17e3x11,true)}},each:function(){},attr:function(_0x17e3x13,_0x17e3x14){type=  typeof (_0x17e3x13);if(type=== _0xafdc[16]){if(_0x17e3x14!= undefined|| _0x17e3x14!= null){volt= t[_0xafdc[2]][_0xafdc[45]](_0x17e3x13,_0x17e3x14)}else {volt= t[_0xafdc[2]][_0xafdc[46]](_0x17e3x13)}}else {for(var _0x17e3xb in _0x17e3x13){volt= t[_0xafdc[2]][_0xafdc[45]]([_0x17e3xb],_0x17e3x13[_0x17e3xb])}};return volt},ajax:function(_0x17e3x15){var _0x17e3x16;if(window[_0xafdc[47]]){_0x17e3x16=  new XMLHttpRequest()}else {_0x17e3x16=  new ActiveXObject(_0xafdc[48])};url= _0x17e3x15[_0xafdc[49]];type= _0x17e3x15[_0xafdc[51]][_0xafdc[50]]();dataType= _0x17e3x15[_0xafdc[52]][_0xafdc[50]]();data= _0x17e3x15[_0xafdc[53]];if(type=== _0xafdc[54]){data= t[_0xafdc[2]][_0xafdc[34]](data);_0x17e3x16[_0xafdc[55]](_0xafdc[54],url,true);_0x17e3x16[_0xafdc[58]](_0xafdc[56],_0xafdc[57]);_0x17e3x16[_0xafdc[58]](_0xafdc[59],_0xafdc[60]);_0x17e3x16[_0xafdc[58]](_0xafdc[61],_0xafdc[60]);_0x17e3x16[_0xafdc[58]](_0xafdc[62],_0xafdc[63]);_0x17e3x16[_0xafdc[64]](data)}else {data= t[_0xafdc[2]][_0xafdc[34]](data);_0x17e3x16[_0xafdc[55]](_0xafdc[65],url+ _0xafdc[66]+ data,true);_0x17e3x16[_0xafdc[58]](_0xafdc[59],_0xafdc[60]);_0x17e3x16[_0xafdc[58]](_0xafdc[61],_0xafdc[60]);_0x17e3x16[_0xafdc[58]](_0xafdc[62],_0xafdc[63]);_0x17e3x16[_0xafdc[64]]()};_0x17e3x16[_0xafdc[67]]= function(){if(_0x17e3x16[_0xafdc[18]]=== 4){if(_0x17e3x16[_0xafdc[68]]>= 200&& _0x17e3x16[_0xafdc[68]]< 400){if(dataType== _0xafdc[69]){result= JSON[_0xafdc[71]](_0x17e3x16[_0xafdc[70]])}else {result= _0x17e3x16[_0xafdc[70]]};if( typeof (_0x17e3x15[_0xafdc[72]])=== _0xafdc[0]){_0x17e3x15[_0xafdc[72]](result)}else {console[_0xafdc[74]](_0xafdc[73])}}else {if( typeof (_0x17e3x15[_0xafdc[72]])=== _0xafdc[0]){_0x17e3x15[_0xafdc[75]](_0x17e3x16)}else {console[_0xafdc[74]](_0xafdc[76])}}}}},html:function(_0x17e3x14){var _0x17e3x8=get;var _0x17e3xa=Object[_0xafdc[22]](_0x17e3x8)[_0xafdc[11]];if(_0x17e3x14!= undefined|| _0x17e3x14!= null){if(_0x17e3xa<= 0){_0x17e3x8[_0xafdc[77]]= _0x17e3x14}else {_0x17e3x8[0][_0xafdc[77]]= _0x17e3x14}}else {if(_0x17e3xa<= 0){ret= _0x17e3x8[_0xafdc[77]];return ret}else {ret= _0x17e3x8[0][_0xafdc[77]];return ret}}},empty:function(_0x17e3x14){var _0x17e3x8=get;var _0x17e3xa=Object[_0xafdc[22]](_0x17e3x8)[_0xafdc[11]];if(_0x17e3xa<= 0){_0x17e3x8[_0xafdc[77]]= _0xafdc[3]}else {_0x17e3x8[0][_0xafdc[77]]= _0xafdc[3]}},val:function(_0x17e3x17){var _0x17e3xa=Object[_0xafdc[22]](get)[_0xafdc[11]];var _0x17e3x8=get;var _0x17e3x12=sl;var _0x17e3x18=_0x17e3x17;if(_0x17e3x18=== undefined){if(_0x17e3xa<= 0){return _0x17e3x8[_0xafdc[78]]}else {return _0x17e3x8[0][_0xafdc[78]]}}else {if(_0x17e3xa<= 0){_0x17e3x8[_0xafdc[78]]= _0x17e3x18}else {_0x17e3x8[0][_0xafdc[78]]= _0x17e3x18}}},append:function(_0x17e3x19){var _0x17e3x12=sl;var _0x17e3x8=document[_0xafdc[17]](_0x17e3x12);var _0x17e3x1a=String(_0x17e3x19[_0xafdc[79]](/^[^\>|\s]*/g));var _0x17e3x1b=_0x17e3x1a[_0xafdc[80]](/\</g,_0xafdc[3]);var _0x17e3xa=Object[_0xafdc[22]](_0x17e3x8)[_0xafdc[11]];var _0x17e3x1c=String(_0x17e3x19[_0xafdc[80]](/^<[^>]*>/g,_0xafdc[3]));var _0x17e3x1d=String(_0x17e3x1c[_0xafdc[80]](/<[^>]*>$/g,_0xafdc[3]));var _0x17e3x1e=document[_0xafdc[81]](_0x17e3x1b);var _0x17e3x1f=String(_0x17e3x19[_0xafdc[79]](/^<[^>]*>/g));var _0x17e3x20=String(_0x17e3x1f[_0xafdc[79]](/([a-zA-Z0-9]*\=)['"](?:[^"'\/]*\/)*([^'"]+)['"]/g));var _0x17e3x21=_0x17e3x20[_0xafdc[83]](_0xafdc[82]);_0x17e3x1e[_0xafdc[77]]= _0x17e3x1d;for(var _0x17e3xb=0;_0x17e3xb< _0x17e3x21[_0xafdc[11]];_0x17e3xb++){var _0x17e3x22=_0x17e3x21[_0x17e3xb];var _0x17e3x23=String(_0x17e3x22[_0xafdc[79]](/^[^\=]*/g));var _0x17e3x24=String(_0x17e3x22[_0xafdc[79]](/["']([^"'\/]*\/)*([^'"]+)['"]/g));var _0x17e3x25=String(_0x17e3x24[_0xafdc[80]](/\"/gi,_0xafdc[3]));var _0x17e3x26=String(_0x17e3x25[_0xafdc[80]](/\'/gi,_0xafdc[3]));var _0x17e3x27=document[_0xafdc[84]](_0x17e3x23);_0x17e3x27[_0xafdc[78]]= _0x17e3x26;_0x17e3x1e[_0xafdc[85]](_0x17e3x27)};if(_0x17e3xa<= 0){_0x17e3x8[_0xafdc[77]]+= _0x17e3x19}else {for(var _0x17e3xb=0;_0x17e3xb< _0x17e3xa;_0x17e3xb++){_0x17e3x8[_0x17e3xb][_0xafdc[77]]+= _0x17e3x19}}},fadeIn:function(_0x17e3x2){var _0x17e3x2=_0x17e3x2;var _0x17e3xa=Object[_0xafdc[22]](get)[_0xafdc[11]];var _0x17e3x12=sl;var _0x17e3x8=get;if( typeof (_0x17e3x8)=== _0xafdc[12]&& _0x17e3xa<= 0){var _0x17e3x28=_0x17e3x8}else {var _0x17e3x28=_0x17e3x8[0]};_0x17e3x28[_0xafdc[23]][_0xafdc[86]]= _0xafdc[87];_0x17e3x28[_0xafdc[23]][_0xafdc[88]]= 0;var _0x17e3x29=+ new Date();var _0x17e3x2a=function(){_0x17e3x28[_0xafdc[23]][_0xafdc[88]]= +_0x17e3x28[_0xafdc[23]][_0xafdc[88]]+ ( new Date()- _0x17e3x29)/ 500;_0x17e3x29= + new Date();if(+_0x17e3x28[_0xafdc[23]][_0xafdc[88]]< 1){(window[_0xafdc[89]]&& requestAnimationFrame(_0x17e3x2a))|| setTimeout(_0x17e3x2a,16)}else {if( typeof (_0x17e3x2)=== _0xafdc[0]){_0x17e3x2()}}};_0x17e3x2a()},fadeOut:function(_0x17e3x2){var _0x17e3x2=_0x17e3x2;var _0x17e3xa=Object[_0xafdc[22]](get)[_0xafdc[11]];var _0x17e3x8=get;if( typeof (_0x17e3x8)=== _0xafdc[12]&& _0x17e3xa<= 0){var _0x17e3x28=_0x17e3x8}else {var _0x17e3x28=_0x17e3x8[0]};var _0x17e3x29=+ new Date();var _0x17e3x2a=function(){_0x17e3x28[_0xafdc[23]][_0xafdc[88]]= +_0x17e3x28[_0xafdc[23]][_0xafdc[88]]- ( new Date()- _0x17e3x29)/ 200;_0x17e3x29= + new Date();if(-_0x17e3x28[_0xafdc[23]][_0xafdc[88]]< 0.0){(window[_0xafdc[89]]&& requestAnimationFrame(_0x17e3x2a))|| setTimeout(_0x17e3x2a,16)}else {if( typeof (_0x17e3x2)=== _0xafdc[0]){_0x17e3x2()};_0x17e3x28[_0xafdc[23]][_0xafdc[86]]= _0xafdc[90]}};_0x17e3x2a()},animate:function(_0x17e3x13,_0x17e3x2b,_0x17e3x2){var _0x17e3x28=get[0];var _0x17e3x12=sl;var _0x17e3x13=_0x17e3x13;var _0x17e3x2b=_0x17e3x2b;var _0x17e3x2=_0x17e3x2;for(var _0x17e3xb=0;_0x17e3xb< prefixes[_0xafdc[11]];_0x17e3xb++){if(_0x17e3x2b=== undefined|| _0x17e3x2b=== null|| _0x17e3x2b=== _0xafdc[0]){_0x17e3x28[_0xafdc[23]][prefixes[_0x17e3xb]+ _0xafdc[91]]= _0xafdc[92];if(_0x17e3xb>= (prefixes[_0xafdc[11]]- 1)){}}else {_0x17e3x28[_0xafdc[23]][prefixes[_0x17e3xb]+ _0xafdc[91]]= _0x17e3x2b+ _0xafdc[93]}};if(_0x17e3xb>= (prefixes[_0xafdc[11]]- 1)){setTimeout(function(){t(_0x17e3x12)[_0xafdc[94]](_0x17e3x13)},100)};if( typeof (_0x17e3x2)=== _0xafdc[0]){return _0x17e3x2()}else {if( typeof (_0x17e3x2b)=== _0xafdc[0]){return _0x17e3x2b()}else {}}},getret:function(){return t[_0xafdc[2]][_0xafdc[95]][_0xafdc[14]]},length:function(){var _0x17e3x8=get;var _0x17e3xa=Object[_0xafdc[22]](_0x17e3x8)[_0xafdc[11]];return t[_0xafdc[2]][_0xafdc[95]][_0xafdc[14]][_0xafdc[96]]()},remove:function(){var _0x17e3x8=get;var _0x17e3x12=sl;var _0x17e3xa=Object[_0xafdc[22]](_0x17e3x8)[_0xafdc[11]];for(var _0x17e3xb=0;_0x17e3xb< _0x17e3xa;_0x17e3xb++){_0x17e3x8[_0x17e3xb][_0xafdc[98]][_0xafdc[97]](_0x17e3x8[_0x17e3xb])}},on:function(_0x17e3x2c,_0x17e3x2d,_0x17e3x2){var _0x17e3x12=sl;var _0x17e3x8=get;var _0x17e3x2e=_0x17e3x8[0][_0xafdc[99]];for(var _0x17e3xb=0;_0x17e3xb< _0x17e3x2e[_0xafdc[11]];_0x17e3xb++){console[_0xafdc[74]](_0xafdc[100]);_0x17e3x2e[_0x17e3xb][_0xafdc[21]](_0xafdc[38],function(_0x17e3x2c){var _0x17e3x2f=_0x17e3x2c[_0xafdc[101]];if(_0x17e3x2f[_0xafdc[102]]=== _0xafdc[103]){var _0x17e3x30=_0x17e3x2f[_0xafdc[98]];_0x17e3x30[_0xafdc[98]][_0xafdc[97]](_0x17e3x30)}})}}};t[_0xafdc[2]][_0xafdc[46]]= function(_0x17e3x31){var _0x17e3x8=get;var _0x17e3xa=Object[_0xafdc[22]](_0x17e3x8)[_0xafdc[11]];if( typeof (_0x17e3x8)=== _0xafdc[12]){if(_0x17e3xa=== 0){if( typeof (_0x17e3x8[_0xafdc[104]])== _0xafdc[0]){return _0x17e3x8[_0xafdc[104]](_0x17e3x31)}else {return null}}else {var _0x17e3x19=[];for(var _0x17e3xb=0;_0x17e3xb< _0x17e3x8[_0xafdc[11]];_0x17e3xb++){if(_0x17e3x8[_0x17e3xb][_0xafdc[104]](_0x17e3x31)=== undefined){}else {_0x17e3x19[_0xafdc[27]](_0x17e3x8[_0x17e3xb][_0xafdc[104]](_0x17e3x31))}};return _0x17e3x19}}else {return _0x17e3x8[_0xafdc[104]](_0x17e3x31)}};t[_0xafdc[2]][_0xafdc[45]]= function(_0x17e3x31,_0x17e3x32){var _0x17e3x8=get;var _0x17e3xa=Object[_0xafdc[22]](_0x17e3x8)[_0xafdc[11]];if( typeof (_0x17e3x8)=== _0xafdc[12]){if(_0x17e3xa=== 0){_0x17e3x8[_0xafdc[105]](_0x17e3x31,_0x17e3x32)}else {for(var _0x17e3xb=0;_0x17e3xb< _0x17e3x8[_0xafdc[11]];_0x17e3xb++){_0x17e3x8[_0x17e3xb][_0xafdc[105]](_0x17e3x31,_0x17e3x32)}}}else {_0x17e3x8[_0xafdc[105]](_0x17e3x31,_0x17e3x32)}};t[_0xafdc[2]][_0xafdc[95]][_0xafdc[14]]= {count:function(){var _0x17e3x8=get;return _0x17e3x8[_0xafdc[11]]},get:function(){var _0x17e3x8=get;return _0x17e3x8},row:function(){var _0x17e3x8=get;var _0x17e3xa=Object[_0xafdc[22]](_0x17e3x8)[_0xafdc[11]];return _0x17e3xa}};function doc(){return document}
```

I researched some sites that did a part of the work, leaving it like this:
https://gist.github.com/TiagoPaza/5ef92af4625c099846af8724948913a3

But I need the code completely decrypted, is there any way I can do this or will I have to redo the entire javascript page to make the necessary changes?

Note: The company you created does not have a backup of the decrypted code ...

Comment: The code you've got is decrypted one. It looks obfuscated because a variable apple would be named `_0x17e3xa` in obfuscation

Comment: @MehulMohan is right. There is no way to get back the original variable names.